# Using AngularJS in a Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, angularjs

I am trying to use the Google developer AngularJS library in an extension popup, but I get an error.

> Error: Code generation from strings disallowed for this context
>       at Function (unknown source)
>       at Jb (chrome-extension://jambnlbfljcfpomlclcgphfmkjfiphkb/lib/angular.js:74:18)
>       at k (chrome-extension://jambnlbfljcfpomlclcgphfmkjfiphkb/lib/angular.js:62:357)
>       at Jc (chrome-extension://jambnlbfljcfpomlclcgphfmkjfiphkb/lib/angular.js:64:37)
>       at Lc (chrome-extension://jambnlbfljcfpomlclcgphfmkjfiphkb/lib/angular.js:69:166)
>       at chrome-extension://jambnlbfljcfpomlclcgphfmkjfiphkb/lib/angular.js:74:241
>       at chrome-extension://jambnlbfljcfpomlclcgphfmkjfiphkb/lib/angular.js:51:270
>       at F (chrome-extension://jambnlbfljcfpomlclcgphfmkjfiphkb/lib/angular.js:47:339)
>       at X (chrome-extension://jambnlbfljcfpomlclcgphfmkjfiphkb/lib/angular.js:39:390)
>       at t (chrome-extension://jambnlbfljcfpomlclcgphfmkjfiphkb/lib/angular.js:38:286)

What is the proper way to write the following content_security_policy directive for a Google Chrome plugin manifest file?:

```
"content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'; script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'",
```

currently it is throwing an error...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You have to use CSP mode in angular to be inside Chrome extension. See: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/893

Basically you have to declare your app as:

```
<html ng-app="" ng-csp>
```

Answer (score 11):

`<html ng-app="" ng-csp>` causes an error in Chrome stable M21 in a chrome-extension://*.xhtml file.

`<html ng-app="" ng-csp="">` appears to work.

Comment: That's because the document in question is XHTML. XHTML is XML, and XML doesn't allow attributes without values.