# How to architect a HUD in a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, architecture, google-chrome-extension, angularjs

I am trying to make a Google Chrome extension using `content script`.
My goal is to have a display at the top of the page (which is already working on my own pages) that can interact with the page.

I need things which are very complicated to put together in an extension, due to security policies :

- Using `require.js` on the extension (that works for now, using [this Github repo](https://github.com/nonowarn/content-script-with-requirejs))
- Using a templating engine to describe my display : I need to add a lot of content to the page and I don't think writing HTML in javascript would be a good workflow.
- For my current version I use jade with my server, but this is not possible with an extension. I think I need to use something like `Angular.js` or `Backbone.js`, but I can't make them work on the content script.
- I need a lot of communication between my extension and the page : For example I need to detect almost constantly mouse moves
- I need communication with my server using `socket.io`

Every bit of functionality of my extension have been developed and tried in a standalone web page, but now I need to integrate it in a real extension and I am really stuck

So due to these requirements, I am wondering what would be the right approach for building this : putting it all in an iFrame (would the server-side communication work? And how to communicate with the page ?), or a way to make a templating engine work nicely in there, or a solution I didn't think of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- Develop the HUD part as a standalone page that the content script will include in an iframe.  You [should be able to use Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11336969/331508) etc. with this, but you will need local copies of as much as possible and you'll need appropriate entries in the `manifest.json` to get it working in the extension.  See/create other questions for the details.
- Have your content script *inject* the code to monitor mouse-moves, etc. into the target page.  Have this code digest and summarize the data, so it's not spamming the system.  Maybe message the summaries to the HUD page and/or content script five or six times a second.

After that, it should just be a matter of getting the pieces working, one at a time.  Break it down to specific problems and ask a question on one specific problem at a time (If you can't find the answers in previous questions).

I'm pretty sure what you appear to want is do-able, but the details are too broad for a single Stack Overflow question.