# AngularJS not rendering in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, firebase

I been trying to get AngularJS working in my Chrome extension, and I'm using the ng-repeat function to create a wordlist.

Here's the HTML of my Chrome extension:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <script src="../firebase.js" ></script>
    <script src="../action.js" ></script>
    <script src="../angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="browser_action.js" ></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #mainPopup {
            padding: 10px;
            height: 200px;
            width: 400px;
            font-family: Helvetica, Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 2em;
        }
    </style> 

    <div ng-app='myApp'>
        <div ng-controller="AppController">

          <div ng-repeat="(f1, f2) in steps">
            <p> {{f1}} : {{f2}} </p> 
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Here's the script browser_action.js, the JavaScript file that deals with the Chrome pop-up:

```
var wordThere 

fireBank.on("value", function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    wordThere = snapshot.val();
})

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.steps = wordThere;
    console.log("loaded");
});
```

The `var wordThere` is just an object with a list of key-value pairs that I retrieved from firebase:

```
var wordThere = {
  "alimaniere (ali·manier·e ← manier·o)" : "differently",
  "la" : "the",
  "milito (milit·o ← milit·i)" : "war",
  "mizero (mizer·o)" : "misery",
  "reakciulo (reakci·ul·o ← reakci·o)" : "reactionary",
  "senfina (sen·fin·a ← fin·i)" : "everlasting",
  "tia" : "such, such a, that kind of, that sort of"
};
```

I used JSFiddle to test out the AngularJS part of the code and it seemed to run fine, but when I packaged everything into a Chrome extension the pop-up doesn't display anything.

http://jsfiddle.net/Baleno/7r4e6zvy/

Comment: Rightclick the toolbar button, select `Inspect popup` and check what are the error messages in the console. See also the first google hit: [Using AngularJS in a Google Chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11336969)

Comment: I added the ng-csp and nothing seems to have changed. Also there is no error in my console.

Comment: yeah, no error messages. And I can type in the var angular, which means angularjs is running

Comment: Try the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp), it lists multiple methods.